# How would you write exaggerated emphasis?

Tags: emphasis

In textual conversations in English, one might write “I’m sooooo excited for the concert tonight!” or similar statements where typically a vowel is repeated for the sake of “exaggerated emphasis.” Is there a similar method for displaying this sort of thing in Japanese? For instance, the above phrase is translated (via google) to “今夜のコンサートにとても興奮しています!” Varying the number of Os doesn’t seem to impact the output. How would one represent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do basically something similar to English.

「今夜のコンサートがすごーく楽しみです！」(I think this is a slightly more natural phrasing)

You can also use すっごく or すんごく (and honestly I think this way is more common in this particular situation). とても can be emphasized as とっても.

You can also add in more, like すんんごく楽しみ or よーーーくわかる, but this may start to look a little silly.

Comment: I also often see people just insert the small forms of hiragana vowel characters (ぉ, ぁ, etc) to indicate a drawn-out vowel.  (i.e. すごぉぉく)

Answer (score 1):

You sometimes see people use katakana to emphasise 今夜のコンサートメッチャ楽しみしているsuch as in the title of this random video メッチャすごいフィギュア見つけた！https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hmmJzNu7cyI

Comment: `楽しみしている` should be 「楽しみ**に**している」